# Are images posted on MSE checked for viruses, malware, adware, ransomware...

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

Does MSE and maybe all of the SEs check posted images for malicious code?

Comment: Would you give a reference link for JPEGs or PNGs with malicious code?  I'm curious what context you have in mind.

Comment: I cannot provide that, I got some nasty malicious code on my computer and I visit very few sites and suspect I got it from one of the sites I frequent. So, it got me to thinking how easy it would be for a bad guy to embed badness in figures people are posting on this site or linking to external sites. That is why I was curious if MSE is scanning pictures that are being posted in questions or answers.

Comment: Unless your system is awfully outdated, you will not get a virus through an image file. It's more of a myth (and the result of people blindly clicking on "virus.jpg.exe" files) than anything.